# when I make ajax post to external server will my server php.ini settings apply?

Tags: php, ajax, post, input

When I POST a file via XMLHttpRequest to external web server, do any of the following `php.ini` input settings on my web server apply:

```
[PHP]
upload_max_filesize = 128M
post_max_size = 150M
max_input_time = 1200
```

*I cannot make test upload to external server, for undisclosed reason, so I have to ask here, in order to know for sure.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The configuration of the server you are making the request to matters.

The configuration of the server hosting the HTML document or JavaScript file that is instructing the browser to make the request does not matter.